# Handling multiple javascript objects inside plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I've created a simple javascript plugin which allows me to collect data from specific html elements. A page can have x amount of elements (Usually up to 20) and each element will have their own settings. My problem is that the returned object is not valid JSON format because i'm getting error "Multiple JSON root elements".

I think the reason is because of the each function i'm using inside the plugin, which creates an new objects for each object and i have tried to solve this; with bad results.

All help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

**Sample plugin**

```
(function($) {

$.fn.collect_data = function() {


    this.each(function() {

        var id = "#" + ($(this).attr("id"));

        // Get numerical value of id
        var get_package_id = function() {
            var package_id = id.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
            return package_id;
        }       

        // Packages is the top level container
        var get_packages = function() {
            var packages = {};

            packages = ({[get_package_id()]: {}});
            return packages;
        }


        // Demo information for each invidual package
        var get_package_info = function() {
            var info = {};

            $(id).each(function() {

                info = ({
                    value: 'Some value', 
                    another_value: 'Another value'
                });
            });

            return info;
        }

        // Demo information for each invidual package
        var get_more_info = function() {
            var more_info = {};

            $(id).each(function() {

                more_info = ({
                    value_more_info: 'Some value', 
                    another_value_more_info: 'Another value'
                });
            });

            return more_info;
        }           

        // Combine the demo information
        var result = function() {

            var packages = get_packages();
            var info = get_package_info();
            var more_info = get_more_info();

            packages[get_package_id()].info = info;
            packages[get_package_id()].more_info = more_info;

            return packages;
        }

        $("#show-data").append(JSON.stringify(result(), null, 2));

    });
    return this; 
}

}(jQuery));
```

**Invalid result**

```
                {
  "33": {
    "info": {
      "value": "Some value",
      "another_value": "Another value"
    },
    "more_info": {
      "value_more_info": "Some value",
      "another_value_more_info": "Another value"
    }
  }
}{
  "74": {
    "info": {
      "value": "Some value",
      "another_value": "Another value"
    },
    "more_info": {
      "value_more_info": "Some value",
      "another_value_more_info": "Another value"
    }
  }
}{
  "99": {
    "info": {
      "value": "Some value",
      "another_value": "Another value"
    },
    "more_info": {
      "value_more_info": "Some value",
      "another_value_more_info": "Another value"
    }
  }
}{
  "124": {
    "info": {
      "value": "Some value",
      "another_value": "Another value"
    },
    "more_info": {
      "value_more_info": "Some value",
      "another_value_more_info": "Another value"
    }
  }
}{
  "124": {
    "info": {
      "value": "Some value",
      "another_value": "Another value"
    },
    "more_info": {
      "value_more_info": "Some value",
      "another_value_more_info": "Another value"
    }
  }
}
```

All data should probably be inside the top-level {} container instead of each object being added inside their own {}.

Thanks for all help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talk about completely over-engineered code. What's the point of all those functions that are only ever called once? Why make a plugin that you can't re-use for anything?

Let's deflate your code into what it actually does:

```
var data = $("foo").map(function () {
    return {
        package_id: "#" + this.id.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''),
        info: {
            value: 'Some value', 
            another_value: 'Another value'
        },
        more_info: {
            value_more_info: 'Some value', 
            another_value_more_info: 'Another value'
        }
    };
}).toArray();

$("#show-data").text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

---

Side note:

Don't use data structures like this:

```
{
   "uniqueID1": {"some": "data"},
   "uniqueID2": {"some": "data"},
   "uniqueID3": {"some": "data"}
}
```

that's misusing an object as an array.

What you really want to create in such a case is an array. It will make life *much* easier for all parties involved.

```
[
   {"id": "uniqueID1", "some": "data"},
   {"id": "uniqueID2", "some": "data"},
   {"id": "uniqueID3", "some": "data"}
]
```

Comment: Hey Tomalak,

Plugin is for learning purpose because i'd like to learn to understand what they're and how to use them. Also, idea was that i could use that plugin all over other page and make it more versatile. However, your suggestion is very good and much appreciated. I'll see how it fits into this specific needs. Thanks for giving good advices :)

Comment: You can re-use the function in my example, too. Just extract it from the `.map()` and give it a name. Your situation is not a good use-case for a plugin. Plugins should manipulate the DOM in some way, otherwise they are pointless.

Comment: @Griphon Your main mistake was trying to build JSON by string concatenation (appending text to an HTML element is the same thing). Don't do that. Build a data structure (object, array, array of objects, whatever). Converting it to JSON is the *last* step, only done directly before you send it via the network or save it somewhere. JSON should be considered immutable. Don't append to it, don't search and replace in it, it's for storage or transfer only. Any changes you want to make require parsing the JSON, changing the data structure, and turning the changed data structure back into JSON again.

Comment: That's very good information and something of which i was not aware of. This helps a lot in the future when learning better practises. Thanks for all the help because it solved the problems. I'll mark this post as answered :)